# Trying out code snippet in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Tags: c++, eclipse, code-snippets

I want to try out a C++ code snippet before actually using it in my project.
I'm quite new to Eclipse. Is there anyway to build and run it quickly in Eclipse ?
I use:
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Helios Service Release 1
Thanks!

Comment: Look up a small "hello world" demo, there should be a million online. You just need a `main()` and as long as your syntax works, you can build and run it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. But I can write a code snippet. I'm not able to build it Eclipse. The question is more about how to do this in Eclipse. I have done this before in Visual studio.

Comment: I found Eclipse so hard to configure for C/C++ and so bloated these days, (I'm using mingw32-w64 compiler) that I went for CodeBlocks, much more easy to configure. Maybe this guide can help you : http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/cdt.jsp

Comment: right click on the project and check the properties and make sure you build c/c++ make file etc is setup. I agree I stopped using eclipse in favor of just plain old vim.

Comment: I see that the toolChain option in the above link has Linux GCC. But in my eclipse setting , it shows as OtherToolChain. I need to install a compiler? Is it available as an eclipse plug-in?